# Find the genereal solution of the second order nonhomogenous differential eq?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the second order nonhomogeneous differential equation
$$y''+2y'-3y=x^2e^x + 3xe^x$$

so what I cant figure out here is what is $y_p$, and how do I find it?? I guess I will have to find it separately for $x^2e^x$ and $3xe^x$ (so I will have to find two $y_p$'s?) and then solve it like it was two separate equation with each respective term on the right side and then just add the particular solutions together with the general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

You have the complementary (homogeneous) solution as:

$$y_c(x) = c_1 e^{-3x} + c_2 e^x$$

Since we have a coincident term (note we have the ODE solution yielding $x e^x(x+3)$, so our homogeneous has a 'common' $e^x$ term in it with the solution) with the homogeneous solution, choose:

$$y_p(x) = xe^x(a + bx + cx^2)$$

The derivatives yield:

- $y'_p(x) = e^x \left(a+b x+c x^2\right)+e^x x \left(a+b x+c x^2\right)+e^x x (b+2 c x)$
- $y''_p(x) = e^x x \left(a+b x+c x^2\right)+2 e^x \left(a+b x+c x^2\right)+2 e^x x (b+2 c x)+2 e^x (b+2 c x)+2 c e^x x$

Substitute these into the ODE (do not forget the constants in the ODE to multiply the above with) and solve for the constants, which yield:

$$a = -\dfrac{5}{32}, b = \dfrac{5}{16}, c = \dfrac{1}{12}$$

Write the final solution:

$$y(x) = y_c(x) + y_p(x)$$

**Update**

When you substitute in $y'', 2y', -3y'$, you should end up with:

$$2 e^x (2 a + b + 4 b x + 3 c x (1 + 2 x)) = x^2e^x + 3xe^x$$

We eliminate the exponential and then equate terms:

$$2 (2 a + b + 4 b x + 3 c x (1 + 2 x)) = x^2 + 3x$$

We have:

$$4 a + 2b = 0, 8 b + 6c = 3, 12 c = 1$$

this yields the numbers above.

Comment: Excellent! You got it, now solve for the constants by equating like terms. Clear?